# Android edge to edge gradient

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to get a gradient inside a rectangle to look like this

[image]

The closest I get using following xml is

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:type="radial"
        android:startColor="@color/lightPurple"
        android:endColor="@color/lightGreen"
        android:gradientRadius="600"
        android:angle="270"
        android:centerX="1"
        android:centerY="0"/>

</shape>
```

Is there anything I can do to make my gradient go from the top right corner to bottom left corner?

Answer (score 1):

Try `android:type='linear'` and `android:angle='45'`.

This would get you more ***closer*** to *edge-to-edge*. Android **doesn't provide arbitrary angles** for this. The only valid angles are the ones which are a multiple of `45`. However as far as I can see, the gradient you require is not actually edge-to-edge and I suspect it to be the one with angle `45`.

Comment: Yea I tried that. It looks pretty much the same as my example above (not my goal)